Terraform create SQL Server instance with self-managed Active Directory
I need your help on this: we have a simple Terraform code to create a SQL Server instance, but I've asked to add it to Active Directory.
I've tested in AWS console, and I was able to join db to AD, now I need to modify the Terraform code to create a SQL Server RDS instance and enable Microsoft SQL Server Windows authentication with self-managed Active Directory.
This is the code we have to create a SQL Server instance:
resource "aws_db_instance" "new_sql_server_instance" {
  identifier                 = var.cluster_name
  engine                     = var.engine
  engine_version             = var.engine_version
  instance_class             = var.instance_class
  username                   = var.master_username
  password                   = var.master_password
  port                       = var.port
  license_model              = "license-included"
  storage_encrypted          = true
  storage_type               = "gp2"
  allocated_storage          = 100
  final_snapshot_identifier  = "final-snapshot-sqlserver"
  db_subnet_group_name       = aws_db_subnet_group.db_subnet_group.name
  multi_az                   = true
  vpc_security_group_ids     = [aws_security_group.dba_security_group_ip.id, aws_security_group.app_security_group_ip.id]
  skip_final_snapshot        = true
  backup_retention_period    = 7
  backup_window              = "03:00-04:00"
  maintenance_window         = "sun:05:00-sun:06:00"
  apply_immediately          = true
  parameter_group_name       = aws_db_parameter_group.rds_instance_parameter_group.name 
}

I think that those are equivalent for first 2 ones (FQDN and Domain organizational Unit)
# Windows Authentication with Active Directory
  domain_fqdn                     = "xxxxx"
  domain_ou                       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

but I don't know how to put others 3 pending ones.
Any idea how to make it work?
Thanks!


There should be a way to add those, it's only that some of the arguments are required for a certain combination. Since you have opted to use domain_fqdn and domain_ou, the following arguments are required:

domain_auth_secret_arn
domain_dns_ips

As the documentation says the following for both:

(Optional, but required if domain_fqdn is provided)

